# how to set dynamic pageSize in element-plus Layout grid?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, element-plus

```js
<el-col
          v-for="i in listVariables.list"
          :key="i.id"
          :xs="12"
          :sm="12"
          :md="8"
          :lg="8"
          :xl="6"
        >
          <ProjectListItem :project-info="i" @refresh-list="getListData" />
</el-col>

<el-pagination :page-sizes="pageSize"/>
```

how to config pageSize by window width?
`pageSize =  gird * 3`

| grid name | pageSize |
| --- | --- |
| xs | 6 |
| sm | 6 |
| md | 9 |
| lg | 9 |
| x6 | 12 |

have any idea?
Have no idea at all by me

Comment: You can use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) api.

Answer (score 0):

I watched window to change pageSizes
I don't know if you have a better idea

```js
const pageSizes = ref<number[]>([])

  const pageSize = computed(() => {
    if (width.value < 768) {
      return 6
    } else if (width.value < 992) {
      return 6
    } else if (width.value < 1200) {
      return 9
    } else if (width.value < 1920) {
      return 9
    } else {
      return 12
    }
  })
  watch(
    pageSize,
    (val: number) => {
      listVariables.pagination.pageSize = val
      pageSizes.value = [1, 2, 5, 10].map((i) => i * val)
    },
    { immediate: true },
  )
```